# Get the <meta> content and assign it to a div jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this `<meta content='Stunning Fashion Photoshoot Project' name='description'/>` on my page and I would like to assign it's `content` on `<div class="description"></div>`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.attr` to  get the value and and assign the meta content to your div using `.html`

Read more about `.html` [here](https://api.jquery.com/html/) and `.attr` [here](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Edit: to Just get the meta where name  is description just use this `meta[name="description"`

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
//Get Meta
var getContent = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');

//Assign to DIV
$('.description').html(getContent)

//Assign to DIV
console.log(getContent)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<meta content='Stunning Fashion Photoshoot Project' name='description' />

<div class="description"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysHelping. But what if I have several `<meta content=''>` tags on my page? I want to get only the `<meta content=''>` with `name='description'`. Do you have some solution for this case?

Comment: @KimSantos Let me update my answer to what you want.